# Why to initialize an array in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I'm doing a [DataCamp course](https://learn.datacamp.com/courses/statistical-thinking-in-python-part-1) on statistical thinking in Python. At one point in the course, the instructor advises initializing an empty array before filling it with random floats, e.g.

```
rand_nums = np.empty(100_000)
for i in range(100_000):
    rand_nums[i] = np.random.random()
```

In theory, is there any reason to initialize an empty array before filling it? Does it save on memory? What is the advantage over the code above as compared to simply the following:

```
rand_nums = np.random.random(size=100_000)
```

Comment: On the contrary, initializing and sampling a Numpy array in one go, like you suggest, is much preferred, as it will be done from C code. Much faster than slooooow Python loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to do this. The second way is faster, more readable and semantically correct.

Besides that, `np.empty` actually does NOT initialize the array - it only allocates memory, but now it contains arbitrary data left in memory from this and other programs.

Answer (score 0):

If all the code they provided is just like above, your way of initializing is better.

Their code might lead to something else later on

```py
rand_nums = np.empty(100_000)
for i in range(100_000):
    rand_nums[i] = np.random.random()
    # maybe they will something else in here later with rand_nums[i]
```